# how to get python to add a string together?

Tags: python, string, range

Here is a small chunk of a code I have:

```
studentName = ""

def getExamPoints (total):
    for i in range (4):
        total = 0.0
        examPoints = input ("Enter exam score for " + studentName + str(i+1) + ": ")
total = ?????
total = total/.50       
total = total * 100
```

where the ????? is I can't figure out how to get the string to add the four scores

student name I inputed later and it is required that later in the program I use `examPoints = getExamPoints(studentName)`.

Answer (score 1):

Without any error checking for bad input:

```
total = 0.0
for i in range (4):
    total += int(input ("Enter exam score for " + studentName + str(i+1) + ": "))
total = total/.50       
total = total * 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```
total += int(examPoints);
```